# Convert string representation of list to list in dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dataframe

I have cvs file like this:

```
number    file
  1       [file1,file2]
  2       [file1]
  3       [file3,file4]
```

with datatype of column `file` is `list`. But when I read that file again, I got datatype of column `file` is `str`. The output is like this:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
>>> for col in df:
>>>    print (df[col].apply(type))
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
....
```

But, I want to read that value as a list. I've tried this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/1894296/10907221]. But I can't apply it to dataframe. Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: what was the error when you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list/1894296#1894296 ?

Comment: @MedAli I updated the question, I want to apply [https://stackoverflow.com/a/1894296/10907221] to my dataframe. But, I don't know how

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to have more than one file per number you should transform your input to:

```
number    file
  1       file1
  1       file2
  2       file1
  3       file3
  3       file4
```

Then to select them as a list you can do:

```
df[df["number"] == 1]
```

Or any number you want.